# How to describe a dish that is both salty and sweet?

Tags: word-choice

We often use the word `savoury` to describe salty and spicy dishes. And the definition on many online dictionary seems to `salty or spicy; not sweet`.

Is there a word that describes dishes in general which are not desserts? For example, Sweet and Sour chicken, can I call that savoury? It might be more sweet and salty. If so, are the common definitions inaccurate?

Can I use the word `umami` to describe it?

Comment: you might as well use "umami" - this "we don't have a word in English to discuss salty & sweet" issue is discussed a lot! I'd say it's now an official "loanword" - so just use it.

Comment: I think a polarised categorisation of taste into *sweet* and *savoury* is essentially a European, perhaps especially an Anglo Saxon notion. (I would be interested to hear from @Mary Lou as to whether Italians so categorise food.) It is perhaps reflective of such 'opposition thinking' that the Oxford Dictionary (not OED)actually defines the word *savoury* as *salty or spicy rather than sweet*. It is also possibly  surprising, in this day of a globalised society, that a British dictionary, in this instance, reflects such parochial thinking.

Comment: According to [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/wordofmouth/2013/apr/09/umami-fifth-taste) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umami), Umami is one of the five basic tastes (together with sweet, sour, bitter and salty). So it cannot be used to describe a combination of any of the other four.

Comment: @WS2 In italain it's either [*agrodolce*](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/agrodolce) (literally "bitter sweet"=sweet'n'sour) or [dolce e salato](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2385056) *sweet and salty/savoury* Foods that contain wine vinegar and olive oil are the former, think pickled food but sweeter/less sharp.

Comment: @andy256 .. exactly. These are the 5 _tongue-sensed_ tastes, detected independently of the olfactory system, objectively measured. There are no cultural biases here.

Answer (score 4):

You can just say **sweet and salty**!

[sweet and salty lollies http://www.cspnet.com/sites/default/files/styles/300_x_225/public/main/articles/snyders-sweet-salty.jpg](http://www.cspnet.com/sites/default/files/styles/300_x_225/public/main/articles/snyders-sweet-salty.jpg)

[sweet and salty popcorn http://www.nila.co.uk/images/products/thumbnails/400/p1004384_1317637320_popcorn_3d_new_sweet.jpg](http://www.nila.co.uk/images/products/thumbnails/400/p1004384_1317637320_popcorn_3d_new_sweet.jpg)

[sweet and salty icecream http://velveticecream.com/wp-content/uploads/SweetSaltyCaramelCHURN_Ill-large.jpg](http://velveticecream.com/wp-content/uploads/SweetSaltyCaramelCHURN_Ill-large.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is a colloquial and uncommon word: ***swalty***.

It is obviously a portmanteau word made by combining *sweet* and *salty*.

> having a salty and sweet taste
>
> *This homemade chocolate is good and swalty. You must have used salted peanuts in it.*
>
> <sub>http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=swalty</sub>

<sub>Note: Urbandictionary also mentions another meaning of the word: Having the consistency, feel, and/or taste of something *sweaty* and *salty*.</sub>

Answer (score -3):

Umami has been incorporated as one of the traditional taste senses alongside sweet, sour, bitter and salty. The issue with using umami here is that it carries it's own meaning, the feeling of savoury or meaty.<sup>1</sup>

If you really want to convey the specific idea of something that tastes both salty and sweet, like nuts dusted with both salt and sugar, just stick with **sweet and salty**, same as we use **sweet and sour** everywhere.<sup>2</sup>

---

1. http://www.msginfo.com/about_taste_umami.asp
2. See all the packages that use these kinds of terms.

Comment: Umami is described by users as a 'meatiness or body' which, while being savoury in nature, doesn't lend itself to how you have described it (neglecting the direct translation as being insufficient).

Comment: Not sure why all the markdowns. I cleaned up my answer a bit and included a reference. Hopefully it clears it up.

Comment: Aldfrith, the downvotes are probably not about how clean your answer is. It's probably because the think you are wrong (other comments here state that umami is a fifth distinct taste, not a combination of sweet and salty.

Comment: I like the clarified meaning of Umami, but meal is more a superset of dessert than a companion, and certainly not an opposite (that would be something more akin to famine). I think, given dessert is defined as 'the sweet course eaten at the end of a meal' that main/starter/meat course/fish course/other would all qualify the requirement of the question, but main course/dish is probably the most common and general.

Comment: I realise my original answer regarding Umami did not carry the meaning I intended. Sorry about that. As for meal, you're right about the opposite being something more akin to fasting, however I meant in this sense that it would be the opposite taste-wise as per his question. For me, I have my meal, and then desert. Or I'll have desert completely separate. I suppose the definition here varies, I'll remove it since it doesn't add much to the answer.